# How to dynamically display image tag after onload

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

This React code works:

```
  const img = new Image();
  img.src =
    'https://storage.cloud.google.com/images.eng.ph.com/uploads/images/c4a-1500x500-logo.jpeg';

  img.onload = () => {
    const el = document.getElementById('image-container') as any;
    if (el) {
      while (el && el.lastChild) {
        el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
      }
      el.append(img);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="main-logo-image-container" id="image-container"></div>
    </div>
   )
```

we set the CSS for .main-logo-image-container to be the same dimensions as the image. But my question is - is there a way to do this with more HTML and less JS? Something like this:

```
  return (
    <div className="container">
       {imageLoaded ? <img onload={setState({imageUploaded:true})} src={imageSrc}/> :
      <div className="main-logo-image-container" id="image-container"></div>}
    </div>
   )
```

but I don't see a way to do that since the `<img>` tag does not have an onload attribute?

Comment: Dont understand why you need onload, you could simple validate `imageSrc` and see if there is an image.

Comment: You mean use polling or something? It has to be evented somehow